# Get dinamically table header and dinamically add rows

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to create a table with dynamically adding rows. 
But I need to have a fixed table header that I got dynamically from JSON and table body also generated dynamically.

Here is JSON example

```
data = [
            {
              id: 0,
              title: "control0",
              text: "text 0"
            },
            {
              id: 1,
              title: "control1",
              text: "text 1"
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              title: "control2",
              text: "text 2"
            },
            {
              id: 3,
              title: "control3",
              text: "text 3"
            }
          ]
```

I try to create method, but I get new column instead of ROW

```
 addRow(index, name) {
    this.newDynamic = { id: index, name: name, text: "name" + index };
    this.data.push(this.newDynamic);
    return true;
  }
```

Here is how now it is looking

[image]

But I need like this

[image]

When we click on button **ADD ROW**, I want to add new row but without title (like on picture), but update JSON with new object.

[Here is stackblitz for example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wx24ny?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: You need to change the structure of your JSON.

Comment: @YasharPanahi hi, but I can not change JSON structure because i get this from API and I have request to get this on this way. It will be much easy if I can change JSON, but unfortunately I can not change structure.

Comment: Ok, I have a question ... How do you know how many columns it has?

Comment: @YasharPanahi I understand, on this way I don't know number of col. Let's say that I can change my JSON structure (I will speak with backend guy for change structure), how in that case I can solve this? Do you have some example? Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtytmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: I get it.... can you pls add your answer to ANSWER for my question, and please explain little. I add also a table head in your https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e84mna?file=src/app/app.component.html, because I need col title

Comment: @YasharPanahi pls take a look at column title, do you have Idea for handle this? When i click on ADD NEW ROW i also get duplicated column title